# PetaPoco: How to use the SQL Like keyword ( WHERE Name LIKE '%@0%')

Tags: petapoco

What is the correct syntax for this query?

```
var l=db.Fetch<article>("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%@0%'", 'something');
```

Or should I use `CHARINDEX`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

May be

`var l=db.Fetch<article>("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE @0", "%something%");`

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried this, but I think it is worth trying:

```
var l=db.Fetch<article>("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE @0", "%" + "something" + "%");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have done your mappings (wich the T4 will do for you) then you could infact do it like so:

```
var l=db.Fetch<article>("WHERE title LIKE @0", "%something%");
```

Saves some typing :)

Answer (score 1):

Can try like this also

```
var l=db.Fetch<article>("WHERE title LIKE @0", "%" + "something" + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write `Select * From article`, when you want to get all the fields. You are better off to use `string.format` to include the wildcards

```
var l=db.Fetch<article>("WHERE title LIKE @0", string.Format("%{0}%", yourVariable));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Articulo articulo = new Articulo();

articulo = db.SingleOrDefault<Articulo>("SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [Articulos] WHERE [CodigoEmpresa] = @0 and [CodigoArticulo] LIKE @1 ", CodigoEmpresa, codigoArticulo + "%");
```